# Why doesn't iTerm2 show my login info after changing the shell from zsh to Bash?

Tags: bash, iterm

I switched the Command option in Settings from "Login Shell" to "Command" and added `/bin/bash`. Previously when I ran iTerm2 I'd get:

```
Last login: some date
user@users-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

but after changing it to bash I get:

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
bash-3.2$
```

How do I change it so that I'm getting the same message for Bash?

Comment: You probably don't want /bin/bash as this is outdated (3.2, current is 5.2) version which ships with MacOS. You can use Homebrew to install current bash version and surpress zhs message in your bashrc.

Comment: Because `bash` isn't configured to do so.  That output isn't from `iTerm`, it's from the shell.